# Date format auto changes while reading csv in java

Tags: java, csv

I am reading csv line by line.In csv date format is for eg-27/04/2015 but I read the same line by my java code ,It read it as 27-04-2015.
Can someone please suggest for the same.
Below is my code-

```
try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp = line;// Simply reading it not using any date format.

                System.out.println("line="+line);

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Below is the line ,I am trying to read

```
1/27/2015,B11100054,US_EOD,20141001_00_00_00,20141001_22_26_25,148.50915,147.68575
```

Comment: Are you trying to read it as a date (which is just a day in any format) or text (which is formatted)?

Comment: There isn't *nearly* enough information here. We don't know what code you're using, or what you mean by "it read it as" - how can you tell? Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Don't put snippets of code in comments - instead, put a short but complete program in the question. Note that the code you included there doesn't do any date parsing at all.

Comment: code posted in question.

Comment: Are you opening your csv in excel? That may be autoformatting your date.

Comment: What are attempting to do? Read date value? Convert from `MM/dd/yyyy` to `dd-MM-yyyy`?

Comment: values are stored in csv .I am trying to read it by java code.However I open csv in excel that does not mean format will be change while reading through java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you read each `line` as you do, then you can split it through its separator value.

```
String[] values = line.split(",");  

// if input format is "MM/dd/yyyy", you can read date: 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
Date dateInput = df.parse(values[0]); // Here you have date stored
```

Remember `dateInput` is an object of `java.util.Date`, so it has **NO format**. It's just a date. 
If you need a String containing `dateInput` in other format, just format it using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
String dateStr = df.format(date);
```

Then you can iterate over all other values:

```
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) { // Start from 1 because 0, date, is already read. 
    // read values[i], depending on its contents, or keep them as String
}
```